# Anyway to be alive after universe ends?

Tags: universe, space

We know the universe has end or loop. Popularly there are $3$ ways for it. So we can not stop it but can we maybe escape from it?

Edit: Ikr it looks IMPOSSIBLE. But isn't there ANYWAY?

Comment: Do you mean escape *from all there is*? Where would that be?

Comment: Voting to close. This is not mainstream physics.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri anything tunnel and go if parallel universe is real. Or generate something like a place that won't be affected by outside. Anything..

Comment: @mmesser314 umm k sorry, so where should I share?

Comment: It is not possible to be alive after the end of the universe because the [total entropy will have reached its maximum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe). Therefore it is not possible for any biological processes to occur and therefore no life can exist.

Comment: Not to be discouraging, but our focus is on answering mainstream physics questions. You seem to have misconceptions about the end of the universe, and parallel universes or places outside the universe. These are not science. Perhaps science fiction?

Comment: @user7777777 thanks.

Comment: @mmesser314 okay, i just wanted to ask it here but right that's not the exact place to discuss about cosmology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We know the universe has end or loop.

We don’t know any such thing. In fact, in the [current standard model of cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model), the expansion of the universe will continue, faster and faster, forever. Therefore the premise of your question is false.

Comment: but it's not the only way. There is also other ways like all energy converts, all stars dead and everywhere is dark. There is more.

Comment: There are a large number of cosmological theories, but only one of them has the status of being the current *consensus* theory. This doesn’t mean it’s correct. It just means all the others are less convincing to most cosmologists for now. In no model with an end or a loop can one “escape” from the universe.

Comment: yeah that was explaining, thanks.